# Rails model that joins through a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is this possible?

In an events system an event can have multiple times. (ie, if it is a 3 day event and each day it's at a different time). Each time has a place associated with it. Finally, each place has an address associated with it. Now, can I reference those addresses through my event model?

I'm thinking something conceptually like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :TimePlaces
    has_many :Places :through => :TimePlaces
    has_many :Addresses :through => :PlaceAddresses :through => :Places
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right syntax.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :time_places
    has_many :places, :through => :time_places
    has_many :addresses, :through => :places
```

Despite this should work, you might want to redesign your database. Running a query with too many joins requires an intensive database elaboration and drastically slows down your application.

Comment: I like your idea better about limiting my joins. There should be a more efficient way for me to do this, and I'll find that way.